# Changing a JTextField via a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

All I am trying to do here is make this button display the number 1 in the textfield of my GUI when pressed. For some reason it does not change anything when I press it. I don't get any error codes though.

```
optionOne = new JButton("Option One");
selectionPanel.add(optionOne);
optionOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
optionOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        optionTF.setText(firstOption);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `optionTF`? and what id `firstOption`?

Comment: @Blip, it's an JTextField object...
to OP: are you sure your firstOption String is not empty? Try to run in debugger to see what happens. I'm not good in swing, but i remember if you are using the JPanel to put your objects on, then you need to call the updateUI() method on it for updates to take changes.

Comment: Are you sure that `optionTF` is in the hierarchy?

Comment: Probably has to do with the value of `firstOption`. Put a System.out.println() in there and verify what that value actually is

Comment: declared strings are here (obviously the 2nd and 3rd ones aren't being used yet)                       
 private String firstOption = "1", secondOption = "2", thirdOption = "3";

Comment: Try to debug by putting `System.out.println(firstOption);` just before `optionTF.setText(firstOption);` and see what happens

Comment: I run code from before edit, it works. I don't see a problem at all

Comment: it print "1" in JTextField optionTF

Comment: still nothing with the system out print. and m.cekiera, it does not print when I run it on mine. no idea

Comment: @wolfiejoe it seems that the problem is in code you didn't post at all, even before edit

Comment: before the edit that was my whole program

Comment: @wolfiejoe not whole, there is no actionPerformed method for other components, meaby you trigger another action by mistake

Comment: yeah, it was the whole program.... i don't know what to tell you. there was no more code than what i pasted in before, this isn't a finished program

Comment: can you post the whole code again?

Comment: @Blip you can enter revisions site by clicking 'edited xx mins ago' just under the question

Comment: okay now i've found out whenever i have updated the code, it is still running the same code that I started working on today. so any updates i make at all, even obvious ones like changing the large frame colour to green instead of red, does not work. 3 hours of work lost, great

Comment: @wolfiejoe why? what you use to run app?

Comment: @wolfiejoe when I copied and pasted your original code, I got an error while compiling `CBallMaze.java:7: error: CBallMaze is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class CBallMaze extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
       ^
1 error
` You did implement the `actionPerformed` method otherwise it will not compile

Comment: @wolfiejoe but after i added the method `actionPerformed` without any code in it I did not get any error and also performed as you wanted when I ran the code on my machine.

Comment: So eclipse decided it was time for my code to stop updating. I had to recreate a new workspace, my whole project file, recreate the class file, paste the EXACT same code into this new class file and everything is updating as normal now. AFAIK the code should work now.

Comment: You probably needed to clean your project.

Comment: @user1803551 tried that, nothing happened. whole project died.

Comment: Then create a separate project with only the code above in a frame and see if it works. If it does, start changing it until you see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Meayby try another approch to ActionListener. Don't create the anonymous class by addActionListener(new Action Listener{}); but create a inner class, for example:

```
optionOne.addActionListener(new OneListener());
```

and then in same class add:

```
private class OneListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        optionTF.setText(firstOption);
    }
}
```

and check if this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            optionTF.setText(firstOption);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: still no luck, and ive been trying to change the background colours of my panels and they aren't changing now. it's like that whole bottom panel has frozen and refuses to update

Comment: yes, looks like invokeLater here is not required at all

Comment: `actionPerformed` already executes on the EDT. You really shouldn't try random things